# How to change color of Hamburger icon of Navigation Drawer in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-studio-3.0

I created a new activity with the default navigation drawer, but the default color is black, how to change it?

[image]

I tried this code works, but the animation is not running and can not be clicked

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In Your AppTheme add this**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
<item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it works

Comment: No Need Of Thanks :) @RukySektiawan

Comment: Ya its working for thanks

Comment: Yeap, it is working!

Comment: in 2023 it is still woking.

Answer (score -1):

Add `drawable` pragmatically to **toggle**

```
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
 toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.fi_menu);
```

where `R.drawable.fi_menu` is your custom drawable

Comment: The question is about color not drawable itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can change **Navigation Drawer** item icon and text color by following:

```
app:itemIconTint="#BDBDBD"
app:itemTextColor="#BDBDBD"
```

Add these in your Navigation drawer view.

Comment: This is used to tint icons in drawer item, not drawer toggle (hamburger icon)

Answer (score -2):

By Adding Background to Navigation view we can achieve that.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/bg_dark_color">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Note:**android:background="@color/bg_dark_color"** this will help to change the background color.

Comment: His question is How to change color of Hamburger, not change color of background...please answers according the question.